# Drop Down Menu Items Not in Tab Order

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a web design project and have run into an issue with the navigation menu.  Our [main site](https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/) is created using WordPress and the main menu contains drop down menus which one can navigate using the tab key. In other words, the drop down menu opens upon tabbing over the top-level item and one can navigate through that menu with the tab key. In order to ensure a consistent and accessible user experience I need to recreate this on an outside platform (not WordPress) using HTML, CSS, and Javacript.

Using the code below I have created a drop down menu with the correct look and feel.  Utilizing two event handlers accommodates both people using the mouse and those using a keyboard (I am less knowledgeable about how screen readers would handle this).  Unfortunately I can't seem to tab through the sub-menus, only the top level items ("About", "Accounts", etc.) and am not entirely sure why.  One would think just adding tabindex="0" would put the items in question into the tab order, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  This doesn't seem to be an hugely common problem because I have had only limited success when searching both Google and Stackoverflow.  Does anyone have any insights into the issue?

```js
//For desktop menu
var customMenuHeaders = document.getElementsByClassName('TopMenuItem');
var customMenuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('NavMenuItem');

//Makes the desktop drop down menus visible upon focus
for (let i = 0; i < customMenuHeaders.length; i++){
     customMenuHeaders[i].addEventListener('focusin', function(event){
         for (let j = 0; j < customMenuItems.length; j++){
             customMenuItems[i].style.display = "block";
         }
     });
          customMenuHeaders[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
         for (let j = 0; j < customMenuItems.length; j++){
             customMenuItems[i].style.display = "block";
         }
     });
     customMenuHeaders[i].addEventListener('focusout', function(event){
         for (let k = 0; k < customMenuItems.length; k++){
             customMenuItems[i].style.display = "none";
         }
     });
     customMenuHeaders[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(event){
         for (let k = 0; k < customMenuItems.length; k++){
             customMenuItems[i].style.display = "none";
         }
     });
}
```

```css
.navigation {
font-family: montserrat;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: right;
width: 60%;
position: absolute;
left: 450px;
z-index: 100;
clear: left;
}
.TopMenuItem {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-left: 25px;
}
.TopMenuItem:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
.TopMenuItem a {
color: #000000;
}
.NavMenuItem {
display: none;
text-align: left;
border-top: 2px solid #FFD200;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
width: 250px;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
z-index: 500;
}
.NavMenuItem li {
list-style-type: none;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;;
}
.NavMenuItem li a {
color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation" aria-label="main_navigation" role="navigation">
<ul >
<li class="TopMenuItem"><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/about-the-library/">About</a>
<ul class="NavMenuItem">
<li><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/about-the-library/">About the Library</a></li>
<li><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/visiting-the-library/">Visiting the LIbrary</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>  
<li><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/faculty-info/">Faculty Info</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/maps-and-spaces/">Maps and Spaces</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
<li class="TopMenuItem"><a href="#">Accounts</a>
<ul class="NavMenuItem">
<li><a href="https://illiad.skidmore.edu/illiad/">Interlibrary Loan</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://lucy2.skidmore.edu/vwebv/myAccount?sk=en_US">Renewals</a></li>
<li><a href="https://refworks.proquest.com/">Refworks</a></li>  
<li><a href="https://outlook.com/skidmore.edu">Skidmore eMail</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://thespring.skidmore.edu/">The Spring</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
<li class="TopMenuItem"><a href="#">Services</a>
<ul class="NavMenuItem">
<li><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/borrowing-guidelines/">Borrowing</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://illiad.skidmore.edu/ares/">Course Reserves</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/ill-info/">Interlibrary Loan Info</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://libguides.skidmore.edu/libraryinstruction">Library Instruction</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/technology/">Technology</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>  
<li class="TopMenuItem"><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/home/resources/">Resources</a>
<ul class="NavMenuItem">
<li><a href="https://libguides.skidmore.edu/citingsources">Citing Sources</a></li>  
<li><a href="https://creativematter.skidmore.edu/">Creative Matter</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://digitalcoll.skidmore.edu/">Digital Collections</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://libguides.skidmore.edu/art/images">Images</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://libguides.skidmore.edu/film">Movies</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://libguides.skidmore.edu/music">Music</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://libguides.skidmore.edu/mcnaughton">Popular Reading</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://libguides.skidmore.edu/c.php?g=157773">Primary Sources</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://libguides.skidmore.edu/reference">Reference Sources</a></li> 
</ul>
</li> 
<li class="TopMenuItem"><a href="#">Under Our Roof</a>
<ul class="NavMenuItem">
<li><a href="http://libguides.skidmore.edu/c.php?g=858358">GIS Center</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://lucyscribnerlibrary.reclaim.hosting/special-collections/Special Collections</li> 
<li><a href="https://help.skidmore.edu/">IT Help Desk</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://academics.skidmore.edu/blogs/leds/">LEDS</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.skidmore.edu/mdocs/">MDOCS</a></li>  
<li><a href="https://www.skidmore.edu/it/mediaservices/index.php">Media Services</a></li> 
<li><a href="https://www.skidmore.edu/writingcenter/">Writing Center</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The tab order doesn't affect the actual placement of items on the screen, only the sequence you'll move through the items when TAB is pressed. To change the display order, you'll need to physically rearrange the HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  After reading the comment by Scott Marcus I took another look at the code.  The issue was that the menu items were effectively invisible to the computer since the default display setting was none.  So even once the JavaScript changed the display to block, the child items of the top level li tag were still invisible and thus not accessible via keyboard.

What worked was to change my approach to the menu's visibility status.  Following on a [post](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) from WebAIM, I absolutely positioned the drop down menus off screen and used the script to move them into place when either a focus or mouseover event occurs.  On the surface the effect is the same, but since the content is always **technically** visible to the computer there is no longer any problem with not being able to tab through the menu.